# How can I emphasise the fact that these tiles are sequential?

Tags: interaction-design, buttons, tiles

I'm making a customisable timer using tiles (work period + break period, repeatedly). I want to emphasise the fact that these tiles are sequential (i.e, left to right, up to down). There are a maximum of 8 tiles. I would consider using arrows but that becomes a problem for the arrow between the top-right and bottom-left.

Also, I have two other queries about this:

1. Is it obvious that the green-colour text is a tile for a rest period?
2. How can I make it clearer that the "New Tile" button is a button? It doesn't have a background and instead a dotted border (which is difficult to see because it's not that thick)

[image: The tiles]

Thank you!

Comment: Color alone should not be used as a user-interface feature. (A) A large number of people are color-impaired in their vision, perhaps even more than those who know it. (B) When staring at a panel of colors, human vision will begin to perceive wrong colors (a lesson learned early by astronauts in the space race).

Answer (score 2):

A grid is inherently 2-dimensional. Communicating a preferred direction in a grid is difficult, communicating an explicit and repeating timeline even more so.

I'd avoid grids for this purpose altogether. If you have something with a beginning and an end, a literal timeline would be helpful.

[image: Google calendar screenshot]

If it's something which would loop back on itself, a time circle would be helpful.

[image: time circle mockup]

In both cases, the size of the item is proportional to the actual time taken, and adjusting them can be as easy as dragging the edges of the block.

For a time circle, the length of the loop is probably the only thing which doesn't have a satisfying modification method, and probably needs a "total length of routine" input somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this! When I say "repeatedly", I just mean that in a session, you repeatedly have work periods and break periods until you finish the session - the session itself is not repeated. An example session would be something like: 25m work -> 5m break -> 30m work -> 10m break -> 15m work. I would use the circle design but it seems like it'd be lengthy for a user to set up.
Instead of using a grid, would it be better to use a row of tall tiles? Though, this would make the duration be iffy to work with. I ideally want to fit this into a rectangular space of the same dimensions as the grid.